# Drop partition columns when writing parquet in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe with a date column.  I have parsed it into year, month, day columns.  I want to partition on these columns, but I do not want the columns to persist in the parquet files.

Here is my approach to partitioning and writing the data:

```
df = df.withColumn('year', f.year(f.col('date_col'))).withColumn('month',f.month(f.col('date_col'))).withColumn('day',f.dayofmonth(f.col('date_col')))

df.write.partitionBy('year','month', 'day').parquet('/mnt/test/test.parquet')
```

This properly creates the parquet files, including the nested folder structure.  However I do not want the year, month, or day columns in the parquet files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark/Hive won't write **`year,month,day`** columns in your **`parquet files`** as they are already in ***partitionBy*** clause.

**Example:**

```
val df=Seq((1,"a"),(2,"b")).toDF("id","name")
df.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("id").csv("/user/shu/temporary2") //write csv file.
```

**Checking contents of csv file:**

```
hadoop fs -cat /user/shu/temporary2/id=1/part-00000-dc55f08e-9143-4b60-a94e-e28b1d7d9285.c000.csv
```

**Output:**

```
a
```

As you can see there is **`no id value`** included in the **csv file**, in the same way if you write **`parquet file`** partition columns are not included in the part-*.parquet file.

---

***To check schema of parquet file:***

```
parquet-tools schema <hdfs://nn:8020/parquet_file>
```

You can also verify what are all the columns included in your parquet file.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `df.write.partitionBy('year','month', 'day')`.

These columns are **not** actually physically stored in file data. They simply are rendered via the folder structure that `partitionBy` creates.

Ex. `partitionBy('year').csv("/data")` will create something like:

```
/data/year=2018/part1---.csv
/data/year=2019/part1---.csv
```

When you read the data back it uses the special path `year=xxx` to populate these columns.

You can prove it by reading in the data of a *single* partition directly.

Ex. `year` will not be a column in this case.

```
df = spark.read.csv("data/year=2019/")
df.printSchema()
```

Also @Shu's answer could be used to investigate.

You can sleep safely that these columns are not taking up storage space.

---

If you really don't want to simply see the columns, you could put a view on top of this table that excludes these columns.